# OrientDB - database object not syncronized with current thread

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have a serious problem with OrientDB ODatabaseDocument object in Java.

To prevent the desyncronization between ODatabaseDocument object (templateDb) and current thread, before close the connection, I force with activateOnCurrentThread the syncronization, but when I close the connection, I always get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current database instance (com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx@302a2a53) is not active on current thread (Thread[btpool0-3,5,main]). Current active database is: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx@2040c7d9
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.checkIfActive(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3138)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.command(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:667)
```

My code:

```
finally {
    if (!templateDb.isActiveOnCurrentThread()) {
        templateDb.activateOnCurrentThread();
    }
    templateDb.close();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
String connectionUrl = customer.getDbName();
if (!connectionUrl.startsWith("remote:")) {
    connectionUrl = storageConnectionPrefix + connectionUrl;
}

try {
    ODatabaseDocumentTx g = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(connectionUrl);
    g.activateOnCurrentThread();
    g.open(username, password);
    g.begin();
    return g;
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code about the connection to templateDb ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota: I've updated my question with connection method

Comment: which version of OrientDb are you using?

Comment: Version is: Orient 2.1.4

Comment: I have no problem with this code: ODatabaseDocumentTx templateDb = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/Db1");templateDb.open(user, password);templateDb.begin();try {ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/Db2");db.activateOnCurrentThread();db.open(user, password);db.begin();System.out.println("Count  = " + db.countClass("V"));} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} finally {
if (!templateDb.isActiveOnCurrentThread()) {templateDb.activateOnCurrentThread();
System.out.println("Count TemplateDb = " + templateDb.countClass("V"));
}templateDb.close();
}

Comment: I got IllegalStateException if I comment templateDb.activateOnCurrentThread();

Comment: So, I must always use activeOnCurrentThread before every use of ODatabaseDocument object?

Comment: Sorry my fault, you can comment db.activateOnCurrentThread() because every time you create, open or acquire a database connection, the database instance is automatically set into the current ThreadLocal space

Comment: Ok, but if I remove line g.activateOnCurrentThread(); I always have the issue of this question

Comment: You can see the documentation at this link http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Multi-Threading.html

Comment: So, because the app has been development on Orient 2.0, when there was been the upgrade of Orient version, the development team has ignored this import feature. Thank you for documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In orientDB version 2.1 you must explicit the `activateOnCurrentThread` related to your DB object. Try as follow:

```
templateDb.activateOnCurrentThread();
```

Comment: Yes, I've adopted this solution. You have convert the commetn in answer, I accept it. Thanks